# Calling method from another method in the same class

Tags: javascript

Right now I am trying to call a method from another method within the same class. When I try to do this I get the error

> this.beginConnDrag is not a function

Here is what the class looks like with just the methods of importance shown.

```
    class NEditor {
    constructor() {
        ...
    }

    ...

    beginConnDrag(path) {
        if (this.dragMode != 0) return;

        this.dragMode = 2;
        this.dragItem = path;
        this.startPos = path.output.getPos();

        this.setCurveColor(path.path, false);
        window.addEventListener("click", this.onConnDragClick);
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onConnDragMouseMove);
    }

    onOutputClick(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var path = e.target.parentNode.ref.addPath();
        console.log(e.target.parentNode);
        console.log("output clicked");

        this.beginConnDrag(path);
    }
}
```

This error is being thrown on the bottom line of the onOutputClick() method when it tries to call the beginConnDrag component. If these are not static methods I don't understand why this call is not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `arrow` functions to keep your `this` object unchanged:-

```
class NEditor {
    constructor() {
        ...
    }

    ...

    beginConnDrag = (path) => {
        if (this.dragMode != 0) return;

        this.dragMode = 2;
        this.dragItem = path;
        this.startPos = path.output.getPos();

        this.setCurveColor(path.path, false);
        window.addEventListener("click", this.onConnDragClick);
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onConnDragMouseMove);
    }

    onOutputClick = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var path = e.target.parentNode.ref.addPath();
        console.log(e.target.parentNode);
        console.log("output clicked");

        this.beginConnDrag(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers this worked. Are there any disadvantages to using this notation? I'm new to OO Js and Js in general.

Comment: @John Nope. It's the new ES6 notation. Arrow functions don’t bind `this` to the object that called them. They just use the value of `this` in the scope in which they were defined. You can read more about it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

It's because of wrong binding for `this`

call handler function like below

```
window.addEventListener("click", this.onConnDragClick.bind(this));
```

Comment: onConnDragClick is not the function that can't be called.